# js2-mode customizations not applying

Tags: customize, javascript, js2-mode

No matter what I do, the customizations I apply to js2-mode are not going into effect. The mode is on and working, but with default settings. I've tried changing the default-tab-width to 2 and changing the indent behavior for switch blocks (indented case lines are turned off by default). I'm using Emacs 24.4.1.

Here are the relevant parts from my .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'js2-minor-mode)
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'ac-js2-mode) ;; add auto-complete suggestions

(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
  '(js2-basic-offset 2)
  '(js2-indent-switch-body t))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting `js2-minor-mode` to handle your indentation?

That's not the case.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `js2-minor-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```
js2-minor-mode is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
`js2-mode.el'.

(js2-minor-mode &optional ARG)

Minor mode for running js2 as a background linter.
This allows you to use a different major mode for JavaScript editing,
such as `js-mode', while retaining the asynchronous error/warning
highlighting features of `js2-mode'.
```

Perhaps you actually want to use `js2-mode` instead of `js-mode` as the major mode for editing javascript?

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `js2-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```
;; Installation:
;;
;; To install it as your major mode for JavaScript editing:

;;   (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode))

;; Alternatively, to install it as a minor mode just for JavaScript linting,
;; you must add it to the appropriate major-mode hook.  Normally this would be:

;;   (add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'js2-minor-mode)

;; You may also want to hook it in for shell scripts running via node.js:

;;   (add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("node" . js2-mode))

;; To customize how it works:
;;   M-x customize-group RET js2-mode RET
```